# Как вывести список подписчиков из твиттера в listbox? C#

Tags: c#, twitter-api

Используя TweetSharp считываю список подписчиков. Как мне его вывести в listbox? Вот код:

```
var options = new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions() { ScreenName = "PutinRF" };
            do
            {
                if (cursor != null)
                    options.Cursor = cursor;

                var followersList = ts.ListFollowerIdsOf(options);

                //listBox1.Items.AddRange(followersList.ToArray());

                cursor = followersList.NextCursor;

            } while (cursor != 0);
```

Comment: что пытались сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: ну, есть аккаунт на который подписаны люди. Используя библиотеку TweetSharp пытаюсь их считать. Считывание происходит, а как добавить такую коллекцию в листбокс - не знал(в коде добавление в листбокс закомментировано) но уже нашёл решение: listBox1.DataSource = followersList;